# Appcelerator Android Webview - Google My Maps - No Waypoints or routes in webview

Tags: android, google-maps, webview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am having issues with appcelerator android webview when trying to open this url:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=z17iJvDVJ98I.kUPrdVX_4thA

This url is a Google My Maps url.

The mpa shows but the routes and waypoints layers just don't display. They display on iOS, they also display in chrome on my android, they also display in the android emulator (Genymotion)

For some reason they just don't appear on the android device in the webview of the application.

Anyone had this issue? Any help would be great!

Comment: You can debug webview with Chrome Developer Tools. Does that show any errors in the console?

Comment: I have developer tools installed but I can't see the webview in the device... Do you need to enable something in appcelerator?

Comment: I got the developer tools working but no error message in the console.

Comment: You should be able to browse through the DOM using developer tools. Perhaps that can help to see what is wrong. Titanium uses android.webkit.WebView so I'm afraid this is issue is not related to Titanium though.

Comment: I can't find anything abnormal in the DOM, in fact I can't even find the route in waypoints in the dom.... I resolved to open the url with openUrl and let chrome do the work. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, that's an possible workaround indeed :) Perhaps you should add it as an answer you can accept yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved to open the url with openUrl and let chrome do the work. It would seem that waypoints and routes from Google My Maps don't diaply in the appcelerator webview.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the device the webview component is not up-to-date. Try and see if you can install this component on your device to get a newer webview inside the app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=de

or use https://github.com/UniversalAvenue/TiCrosswalk and you are independent of the installed Webview component of the target device

Comment: My Android device has the latest webview component. I tried installing ticrosswalk. I managed to install the module and add it to my project but my app fails after starting. The error looks like this:
[INFO] : TiApplication: (main) [37,68] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
[ERROR] : art: No implementation found for boolean org.xwalk.core.internal.XWalkViewDelegate.nativeIsLibraryBuiltForIA() (tried

Comment: ah, got the same with the latest version. See: https://github.com/UniversalAvenue/TiCrosswalk/issues/14

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried that and when I pout the <abi>armeabi-v7a</abi> the application crashes at start. IT says TiVerify: Failed to load library